# How to set is_active=False in Django UserCreationForm

Tags: django-forms

I want to do email verification while creating a user in django using "from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm". When a user register into my site then a user will be created but his active status will be false. And a verification code will be sent to his email address, when he enters the verification code his account will be activated.

For this is I want to set:

```
is_active = False
```

And when he enters the verification code, it will be set as:

```
is_active = True
```

But the default value of `is_active = True`. So how I can make it `False`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

all of the changes to python object model will apply to database only when save() method invoked.you can active or deactive status with this sample :

```
user = User.objects.create()
user.is_active = False
user.save()
```

Comment: Where to redirect the user after this? Right now it goes to the home page and gives an error:  **AttributeError at /accounts/register/seller/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'**

Comment: @DerekPK who sends this request, the user itself?admin?anonymous?

Comment: I figured out how to solve this, mine had auto login after registering, so I deleted it, now the error is not showing up.

Answer (score 7):

When the form is saved it appears the user object is returned. You can then use this object to edit the `is_active` status:

```
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    # default to non-active
    user.is_active = False
    user.save()
```

You could instead manage updates to the User instance in a post_save signal (this is a more generic approach and will work whenever creating a new user). In `<your_app>/signals.py` (not tested):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def default_to_non_active(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.is_active = False
        instance.save()
```

Ref. to this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) for more about signals.

Comment: instance.save() on post_save will trigger another post_save()... could be an infinite loop. Better use pre_save() to avoid that...

Comment: @Beki No, it will call the `post_save` just one more time and won't cause an infinite loop because the `instance.save()` is inside the `if created` condition. On the other hand, using `pre_save` without a condition would cause the `is_active` to be false on updating any of the fields in the User model. IMO first solution is better.